# How to edit the main menu?

Tags: linux-mint, xfce

I am trying to edit the main menu.

[image]

There is no menu editor anywhere. I have installed `alacarte` which doesn't seem to work. Also, someone suggested to me "right clicking on the menu and clicking edit", but there is no option.

How are you supposed to edit the menu? I'm using Linux-mint 13 with XFCE.

Thank you.

Comment: The menu file is located at `/etc/xdg/menus/xfce-applications.menu`, you could edit that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Customize the Xfce menu](http://wiki.xfce.org/howto/customize-menu) at the XFCE site.

Answer (score 6):

Since you use Linux Mint 13 (Maya) the file *xfce-applications.menu* is located here: `/usr/share/xfcemint/xfce-applications.menu`
This file is for structure changes (see above). If you want to remove an entry look up the responsibel *.desktop*-file in the user folder e.g. in `~/.local/share/application/`